# Effects of writing the name of a person who has an identical twin with the same name in the death note

Tags: death-note

I'd like to know what would happen in a situation like I'm describing.

If I renember correctly it was needed to both write correctly the name of the person to die and have his image on head.

But if that person has an identical twin with the same name I think those rules wouldn't be enough to determine which of them would die, although maybe with image it also meant the intent of killing that particular person I find that far fetched.

Maybe there are some other rules that would apply and would determine which of them dies, I don't renember all of them.

What would happen in that situation?

Comment: A situation involving twins was briefly discussed in [this](https://anime.stackexchange.com/a/21875/20275) answer. *Even with identical twins, they will have differences*

Comment: when you have the face in mind it means you have the person in mind. the note does not search for a face and a name it searches for a person to kill. identical twins are two different people.

Answer (score 1):

It would probably depend on two things. One of which is the fact that you would only be thinking of one face, not both. The way it works is if you thought of the first twins face, but wrote the name and though of the name belonging to the second, nothing would happen. Even if they had perfectly identical faces, you wouldn't be thinking of both, just one. Identical twins are two separate people, and as such, the death note would still treat it like such.

This idea is based on my personal though about the subject that I've actually thought about for at least a year.